# how can I include multiple values to has and belongs to many relation from various select box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two tables `items` and `sub_category` and I have `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation between two. I have to select values for sub categories from different select boxes and include all those values to the item subcategory.

I have a form where I have one drop down box and multiple select box and both these contain sub categories and I have to include the values from both to the item subcategory. How can I do this?

Comment: Please include your code where you want to include this relateion

Comment: Your problem is not cleared...

Comment: @Ganesh Kunwar : I have posted clearly in another question along with the code. please refer to it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478085/how-can-i-get-the-value-for-association-from-different-fields-and-save-all-the-v

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of book and author example.I think you can change this code with your problem.

```
<%= select_tag "book[author_ids][]", options_from_collection_for_select(Author.all, :id, :name), {:multiple => true, :size => 3} %>
```

Comment: This is what i have but with a little change. Instead of select tag i have used collection select but my question is more than one drop down  box for the same association and selecting mutiple values from all the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly interpretated your question, this example, Rails cast 88, http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised, from rails casts should answer the question.  In this example selecting the country then changes the possible slection choice for states.
Pierre